# Show ranking for year

Tags: discussion

I think my point ranking was #1 in Ask Ubuntu for 2018 but I can't seem to find this. I've started a job search and think this might be helpful. Is there a way to see the point rankings by year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/89/year/askubuntu/2018-01-01

The [users page](https://askubuntu.com/users) has a link to the reputation leagues at the bottom.